# tooltip jquery plugin with ajax support is needed !

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

i need a jquery plugin to show full description of some data as a tooltip when mouse over that data's row in table. the description should load with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [jQuery TOOLS Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html). I use it on my projects.

But as for AJAX, you will probably need to code it yourself with event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, I just recently released my [fork of jQuery UI Tooltip](http://writeless.se/2011/01/jquery-ui-tooltip-widget/).

It supports remote content by feeding a function to the content option that takes care of the ajax request.

Something like this:

```
$("table tr").tooltip({
    content: function(response) {
        // Init the ajax call (you can use .post or .ajax as well)
        // response is the callback that will handle the response
        $.get("url_to_tooltip_content", response);
        // Return text that will show until a response have been recieved
        return "Loading..."; 
    }
});
```